# how to use any bash command to cut a file and save all columns in a different file

Tags: bash, shell

Good day,

I was wondering how to cut a file and save each part in a different file. Where the delimiter is **]**

example:

```
TOfile1 ] TOfile2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F' []] ' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i > "file"i}' input
$ head file*
==> file1 <==
TOfile1

==> file2 <==
TOfile2
```

- Set the delimiter to `[]]`, since `]` is a special character we put it inside character class to consider it literal.
- We iterate over all fields storing each element in a separate file. This gives the answer flexibility to create as many files as there are fields and not just two.

Hence, if your input is something like the following:

```
$ cat input
TOfile1 ] TOfile2 ] Tofile3 ] Tofile4
TOfile1 ] TOfile2

$ awk -F' []] ' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i > "file"i}' input

$ head file*
==> file1 <==
TOfile1
TOfile1

==> file2 <==
TOfile2
TOfile2

==> file3 <==
Tofile3

==> file4 <==
Tofile4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/.*]//' myfile > TOFile2
sed -e 's/].*//' myfile > TOFile1
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be precisely the standard use-case for the [`cut` utility](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#cut-invocation).  Without further ado:

```
cut --delimiter=']' --field=1 input.txt > TOFile1.txt
cut --delimiter=']' --field=2 input.txt > TOFile2.txt
```

I'm using the long option names here for readability.  The short versions are `-d` and `-f` respectively.